# Displaying a view of custom data in a data-grid-view?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm writing a simple winforms application, and I'd like to use a [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) to display some application data (not from a table) to the user.  It is easy to set an `IList` to the `DataSource`, but this requires having a class with the property names and order that you want to display.

How can I create a view over my data/objects for the DataGridView without writing a custom object?

Answer (score 0):

Get your query into a data table then set that as the datasouce. you can use the format/paint event on the dgv to customise how the data appears to the user...

Comment: What query?  The question states that it's "not from a table".

Comment: Sorry, I missed that bit. Would writing an adapter object solve your problem? - this does involve writing a custom object though, but means you don't need to change anything you have already.

Comment: The only other this I can suggest is something like this: http://nerdboys.com/2010/05/25/applying-the-decorator-pattern-to-a-datagridview/3/